# Problems with setting up foreign file repository

Tags: mediawiki, ubuntu-14.04

I installed a MediaWiki instance on my Ubuntu box which is working fine. I used us instant commons but this caused a huge delay on rendering pages.

I therefore decided to implement my own MediaWiki Commons instance as well in order to store images I use for my main wiki. This works fine too.

The problem I am having is with configuring "$wgForeignFileRepos" and in particular the parameter "apibase". Whenever I upload a new image along with description etc. and create a new article on my main wiki instance, I have to change "apibase" path.

For example, I have a starting configuration of:

```
$wgForeignFileRepos[] = array(
   'class'                   => 'ForeignAPIRepo',
   'name'                    => 'privateCommons',
   'apibase'                 => 'http://ubuntu/commonsmediawiki/api.php',
   'hashLevels'              => 2,
   'fetchDescription'        => true,
   'descriptionCacheExpiry'  => 432000,
   'apiThumbCacheExpiry'     => 864000
);
```

Now I add a new image including description to commons, followed by a new article using the just added image. However, the image does not show up.

I now have to change "apibase" to

```
'apibase'                 => 'http://localhost/commonsmediawiki/api.php'
```

to make the image appear. Repeating the process by adding a new image and new article the image does not show again.

Again I have to change "apibase" to any of:

```
'apibase'                 => '//localhost/commonsmediawiki/api.php'
'apibase'                 => '//ubuntu/commonsmediawiki/api.php'
'apibase'                 => 'http://ubuntu/commonsmediawiki/api.php'
```

By doing that the second article displays the most recent image after purging but when I go back to the previously added article the image is gone again.

By the way, I am running the same version of MediaWiki that is used by Wikipedia  (1.26wmf4). My Ubuntu version is pretty up to date (14.04).

I should also mention that both wikis share the images folder which should not be a problem because images will never be stored in both wikis. The two wikis do neither share any tables.

I also tried to use "ForeignDBRepo" which did not work at all saying that the images could not be found which I do not understand either.

I have not the slightest clue how to remedy this very annoying behaviour. So any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure you configured the thumbnailer? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Thumb.php

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the only URL which ever worked was

```
'apibase'                 => 'http://localhost/commonsmediawiki/api.php'
```

so please use that. It must be an URL that the *server* can contact. A fake domain like `//ubuntu/` would need some DNS trick on your end, which you didn't mention doing.

I suspect you didn't set up [cache](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMainCacheType) correctly, so you may try and disable caching for this feature:

```
'descriptionCacheExpiry'  => 0,
'apiThumbCacheExpiry'     => 0
```

and let us know how it worked.